# MYSQL by case when

Tags: mysql

I have a data table like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|   userID   |      dateTime       |   val1    |   val2   |
----------------------------------------------------------
|    abc     | 2014-10-20 00:00:00 |   21.5    |   18.5   |
|    ijk     | 2014-10-21 00:00:00 |   22.5    |   17.5   |
|    pqr     | 2014-10-22 00:00:00 |   23.5    |   16.5   |
|    xyz     | 2014-10-23 00:00:00 |   24.5    |   14.5   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to sort the table by `dateTime` in `desc order` by `val1` in `asc order` and by `val2` in `asc order` but if the user ID matches I want that row on the top always independent of other field.

For this I have a query like this

```
Select * 
from mytable 
order by case 
           when userID = 'abc' then 1
           else 'ordeyByField' end 'order';    
WHERE orderByField = dateTime or val1 or val2 
For dateTime, order = desc
        and
    for val1 or val2, order = asc
```

When I sort it with val1 or val2 it is fine (because the order is asc) but when I sort it with dateTime it shows the matched userID row in last (because order is desc). I want the matched userID row on the top always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, and it's easier than you think it is :-)

```
Select * 
from mytable 
order by case when userID = 'abc' then 0 else 1 end, dateTime desc, val1, val2;
```

Comment: perfect.. That's what I wanted... Thank you very much :)

Comment: Actually, this is what the FIELD() function is for!

Comment: @Strawberry: You can use `FIELD(userID, 'abc') desc` here, but as long as we are dealing with one value only, I would consider that just an alternative, no more. With more values to rank, however, FIELD would definitely be preferrable to case constructs.